# Round-tripping a Java class through the Clojure printer and reader

Tags: java, serialization, printing, clojure, barcode-scanner

I have a Java class `Vector2` that I'd like to persuade to "play nicely" with the Clojure reader.

```
(def a (vec2 1 2))
(print-str a)
=> "#<Vector2 [1 2]>"
```

Ideally I'd like the class to print out in a form that can be read by the Clojure reader. i.e. I'd like the following to return true:

```
(= a (read-string (print-str a)))
```

What is the best way of achieving this round-tripping capability?

Comment: You don't want to involve the `EvalReader`, I suppose?

Comment: @Marko: Open to suggestions. It's not specifically intended for an external API - more for convenience at the REPL and easy serialisation / deserialisation.

Comment: I think with `read-eval` left to true, the reader will know what to do with `#=(Vector2. 1 2)`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide `print-dup` and `print-method` multimethods for your class/type.

Check out [core.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3311)

Ex:

```
(import 'java.util.Hashtable)
(defmethod print-method Hashtable [x writer] 
      (binding [*out* writer] 
         (print (let [h  (gensym)] 
                 `(let [~h (Hashtable.)] 
                     ~@(map (fn [i] 
                               `(.put ~h ~(str "\"" (.getKey i) "\"") ~(.getValue i)  ) ) x) ~h)))  ))
(def a (Hashtable.))
(.put a "a" 1)
(.put a "b" 2)
(= a (eval (read-string (print-str a))))
```

Comment: This seems to cover only the writing end. How does it do reading?

Comment: `read-string` is for reading. Basically this multimethod will return an s-expression in string format like `(vec2 1 2)` that when executed result in creating of the desired object

Comment: This is not what Mikera wants: he doesn't want to `eval` the code into his object; he wants to **read** it, just like a native Clojure vector.

Comment: If that is the case then you can't do that as clojure doesn't have reader macros i.e you can't extend reader except for using tagged literals which are introduced in 1.4 i think

Comment: What about the `EvalReader`? You don't need a separate mechanism. Tagged literals may also be an avenue worth exploring.

Comment: Yes, but that requires `read-eval` to be true and some recent discussion suggested to make it false by default to avoid security issues as more and more clojure web apps are using EDN for data transfer.

Comment: So mikera would have `(binding [*eval-read* true] ...)`. It seems he's OK with that.